# How to divide two dataframes with different length and duplicated indexs in Python

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my code and I want to get the expected output, but, division of dataframes does not work, what is wrong here?

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'name':['A', 'C', 'D'], 'cond_a':['B','B','B'], 'value':[10,12,14]}
data2 = {'name':['A', 'C', 'D','D','A'], 'cond_a':['G','G','G','G','G'], 'value':[5,6,7,3,2]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

df1.set_index('name', inplace=True)
df2.set_index('name', inplace=True)


df2['new_col'] = df2['value'] / df1['value']
```

expected output:

```
     cond_a  value    new_col
name        
   A    G     5        5/10
   C    G     6        6/12
   D    G     7        7/14
   D    G     3        3/14        
   A    G     2        2/10
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as `df1` has a unique index, you can [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) it on `df2` when performing the division:

```
df2['new_col'] = df2['value'] / df1['value'].reindex(df2.index)
```

The resulting output:

```
     cond_a  value   new_col
name                        
A         G      5  0.500000
C         G      6  0.500000
D         G      7  0.500000
D         G      3  0.214286
A         G      2  0.200000
```

Comment: oh, that's clever. thanks, didn't know there was a simple solution here

Comment: @ayhan: Oops, yeah, that's correct.  I switched them in my head because I usually think of the denominator as being the second dataframe!

Answer (score 1):

What doesn't work in your case is not DataFrame division, which you can easily check:

```
df2['value'] / df1['value']

Out[]:
name
A    0.500000
A    0.200000
C    0.500000
D    0.500000
D    0.214286
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

The problem is that in the process of this division `pandas` loses track of the order of index `name`. Then when you are trying to assign the result back to the `df2`, you have duplicates in your index `name` and `pandas` doesn't know how to merge them, because it is an ambiguous situation to have. In general having duplicates in your index is not a good idea. Get rid of the duplicates and your code will work.